# Error opening Oracle*Terminal file fmrweb.res in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-fusion-apps

I have installed Oracle Forms & reports 12.2.1.4 and created a fresh domain, but after creating the domain the "instances" folder under $DOMAIN_HOME/config/fmwconfig/components/FORMS path is not created due to the bug  Bug 25032686.

So I copied the instances folder from another working domain to try and fix it instead of deleting and creating a fresh domain as per the steps in the bug and the forms page is loading and getting below error.

Can anyone please help regarding this issue?

Error opening Oracle*Terminal file fmrweb.res

Many Thanks

Ibrahim

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with Oracle bug 25032686.  In fact, that bug is not a bug.  I was user error.

Your installation likely had issues because the domain was not properly created. It is important to always read the documentation before installing enterprise-class software (or any software for that matter), at least until you become familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks, yes had to create Report tools and server instance using wlst to resolve the above issue, this step is in fact part of domain creation in Oracle Forms & Reports. 

createReportsToolsInstance(instanceName='reptools1',machine='<hostname>')
createReportsServerInstance(instanceName='repsvr_<hostname>',machine='<hostname>')